# Threading and Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have created an application which basically generate graphs and displays them. However due to some processes taking a longer time i had created a loading bar which requires the use of threading.

Everytime i run the application the first time, the subsequent time displaying a heatgraph causes "RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop"

[image: The Application]

Without the use of threading, it would work perfectly fine. I would like to thread and still continuously use graphs.

Sorry for the messy codes.

```
class App(customtkinter.CTk):

    def generate_heatmap(self):
        print('Generate HeatMap')
        brightness = []
        motion = []

        for k in figs_b.keys():
            l = figs_b[k][1]
            brightness.append(sum(l)/len(l))


        for s in figs_m.keys():
            print(s)    
            l = figs_m[s][1]
            motion.append(max(l))

        data = pd.read_csv(filedialog.askopenfilename())
        print(data)
        data.insert(2,'Color',avg_c)
        data.insert(3,'Motion',motion)
        data.insert(4,'Brightness',brightness)      

        sns.heatmap(data.corr(), annot=True, cmap='viridis', vmin=-1, vmax=1)       
        plt.show()      


    def loading(self):      
        if(self.t.is_alive()):  
            print('EXECUTE LOAD')       
            self.main_frame.grid_forget()
            self.loading_frame.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=4,columnspan=4,sticky="nsew")
            self.loading_frame.grid_propagate(False)
            self.loading_lbl.pack_propagate(False)          
            extract_image_from_gif()
            self.play_gif() 
            self.update()
        
        print('RESET LOAD') 
        self.loading_frame.grid_forget()
        self.main_frame.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=4,columnspan=4,sticky="nsew")
        self.update


    def play_gif(self):
        global countx, cur_img
        try:
            print('in')
            countx += 2
            cur_img = customtkinter.CTkImage(lst_image[countx],size=(800,200))
            self.loading_lbl.configure(image = cur_img)
            self.update()
            self.after(gif_duration,self.play_gif)

        except Exception as e:
            #print(e)
            if(self.t.is_alive()):
                countx=0
                self.after(gif_duration, self.play_gif)
            else:
                return

    def openfile(self,force=''):
        name = force
        decision = ''
        if force == '':
            decision = filedialog.askopenfilename().split('/')
            name = decision[len(decision)-1].split('.')[0]

        if name == '':
            return
    
                
                
        self.btn_list.append(customtkinter.CTkButton(self.btn_frame,text=name,command=lambda: self.change_analysis(name)))      
        for x,btn in enumerate(self.btn_list):
            btn.grid(row=x+1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

        print('*'*20)
        self.t = th.Thread(target=self.getGraph, args=(decision,name,))
        self.t.start()
        self.loading()      
        self.t.join()
        self.change_analysis(name)
        print('*'*20)

    def getGraph(self,decision,name):           
        if os.path.exists(f'Frames/{name}') and decision != '':
            return
        elif(decision !=''):
            frame_extraction('\\'.join(decision),name)              

    
        red = []
        green = []
        blue = []

        files = os.listdir(f'Frames/{name}')
        sorted_files = [file.replace('f_','') for file in files]
        sorted_files = sorted(sorted_files, key=lambda x: int(os.path.splitext(x)[0]))

        for frame in sorted_files:          
            rgb = color_extraction(f'Frames/{name}/f_{frame}')
            r,g,b = rgb[0]
            red.append(r)
            green.append(g)
            blue.append(b)
            #print(f'Frame: {frame} RGB:{rgb[0]}')


        frames = [(int(os.path.splitext(x)[0]))*20 for x in sorted_files]

        figs_c[name] = generate_graph(red,green,blue,frames)        

        if(decision != ''):         
            figs_m[name] = motion_analysis(name)
            figs_b[name] = brightness_graph(name)
            print(figs_b[name])         
            self.save_data()

        
        
        avg_r = round(sum(red) / len(red))
        avg_g = round(sum(green) / len(green))
        avg_b = round(sum(blue) / len(blue))        

        avg_c.append(rgbtoint32([avg_r,avg_g,avg_b])
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code/errors. Also the code you posted is too long, please make a [mre]. Main point: `tkinter` doesn't always like being called from a different thread, so avoid calling `tkinter` from threads other than the one where you created the `tk.Tk`

Comment: Matplotib is not thread safe:  https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq/howto_faq.html#work-with-threads. In general sns.heatmap will try to make a new figure - you should probably pass it an axes.

Comment: @TheLizzard, sorry about that, i have a minimal reproduction. The threading is mainly to achieve values from different functions, and does not have any tkinter variables in it. The generation of the heatmap, should be done after the thread has ended.

Comment: @JodyKlymak sorry as i am quite new to this, how do i pass it as an axes.

Comment: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html in the *ax* parameter